# SearchView in AppCompat distorts icon

Tags: android, menu, android-appcompat, searchview

I am stuck in a very weird situation, my **SearchView** is working perfectly. 
I just need to use **OnActionExpandListener** and for that purpose,
I have to set  **app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"**
in my SearchView item in menu layout.

What it does is, it distorts my SearchView icon. 
If I use **app:showAsAction="always"**, **OnActionExpandListener** stops working but icon is shown perfectly.

Any kind of help is this regard will be highly appreciated, thanks.

**Edit:**
See the comments on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, they have failed doing this nicely.
Anyway, I use this instead in order to detect when `SearchView` is being expanded/closed.

```
searchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            // Opened
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
            // Closed
        }
    });
```

Comment: It does solve my one problem, but i really need to use app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" without getting my search icon all messed up. :S

Comment: Why do you need ifRoom? Do you only want to show it if it fits in the actionbar? Otherwise you can use always|collapseActionView

Comment: @ShahrozKhan91: I tried using ifRoom|collapseActionView, it doesn't mess up the icon.

Comment: are you using default android icon for search? i have two fragments one with  ifRoom|collapseActionView and other with always
on always one it picks up android default icon but on other it doesn't.

Comment: @ShahrozKhan91: Nopp, I'm using my own search icon. Post your xml for the item

Comment: I switched to my own icon and i am using it everywhere now. 
I was trying trying the reflection method for getting default search view look but it won't pick the android icon if its 
ifRoom|collapseActionView.Thanks for your time and concern